# Verify download event in playwright for both negative and positive scenario

Tags: typescript, web, playwright, browser-automation

I want to verify that when I click on `save` button, the download event get triggred and it downloads the file and returns filename. and it is working file with following code.

```
    async getDownloads() {
        const download = await this.page.waitForEvent('download');
        return download.suggestedFilename();
    }
```

The second scenario is to verify that when I click on `cancel` button, the download event should not get triggered, and the fuction should return `false` or something.

The issue where I am struggeling is, when I call this function and it does not get the download event, it is giving me error for timeout. How can I verify that, when no downlaod event is triggered, it should return false.

I tried. the `page.on` event, but the issue is, my execution get closed just after clicking on the button and it does not wait for downlaod event. And it is mentioned in the doc also. [Link](https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads#variations)

```
    this.page.on('download', (down) => {
        console.log(down.suggestedFilename());
        return down.suggestedFilename();
    });
    await this.modals.clickSaveButton();
```

How can I modify the function to get filename when downloaded, else false?

Comment: figure it out ?